# Sencha - Add bottom header border to a panel

Tags: html, css, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a panel (extjs panel) and I need to draw only the bottom border of the panel header.

I checked out using firebug to my web application theme that there is a css property that allow to draw a bottom border of a panel header:

```
.x-docked-top{
   border-bottom-width: 0 !important;  // neptune-theme.css
}
```

As I remarked, this property is set via neptune theming template... so I need to set this property to '1' like this:

```
.x-docked-top{
       border-bottom-width: 1 !important;  // myCustomCss.css
}
```

The problem is that I don't know why if I write in my `myCustomCss.css` file the above code, it doesn't work and nothing happen. Maybe the `!important` feature used in `neptune-theme.css` has major priority?.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I ran into this problem recently. It is not possible to target a single border through a Sencha variable. I have only found success in overriding the CSS directly.

The solution you purposed would not work as you are missing the units after the value.

```
.x-docked-top{
       border-bottom-width: 1px !important;  // myCustomCss.css
}
```

However, the class and process should theoretically work. If not, some of the other classes might be more receptive. This is the class that I ended up adding a property to:

```
.x-panel-header-default-horizontal.x-header-noborder {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #BFBFBF !important;
}
```

I wanted no border except for the bottom. The property affects most of the components except for a few cases, requiring additional overrides. (Using Sencha ExtJS 6)